# Microsoft Access query criteria

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Is there any way to phrase a piece of query criteria to ask a question like "What year do you want" and it to return results for every year except that one?

Comment: I voted the question down based on your comments in the posted answer. Are you trying to figure this out or are you just looking for someone to hand you answers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where [Year] <> [What year do you not want?]
```

Comment: So would that be   Select * From Children Where [Year] <> ["What year?"]

Comment: The SQL doesn't read your parameter "prompt", only picks the entered value.

Comment: So assuming that the table is called "children" what would the criteria be?

Comment: The same. I would strongly recommend that you look up a "Beginners Guide to SQL" or similar.